# How to generate one hash key for a directory in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, hash, certutil

This is what I am doing on linux

```
cat a-directory/* | md5
```

What would be the alternative in PowerShell, maybe something with `CertUtil`?

The reason I am doing this is that I want to make sure I can copy a large directory.

Comment: [Get-FileHash](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-filehash?view=powershell-7), but consider using [Robocopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) instead of rolling your own solution.

Comment: `bash -c "cat directory | md5sum"`

Comment: This definitely won't win any beauty awards, but at least returns the same result: `([System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm]::Create('MD5').ComputeHash([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes((gc C:\a-directory\*.*) -join '')) | % { $_.ToString('x2') }) -join ''`